# Javascript - Id value Increment rows Does Not Work and Remove Rows By Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, rows

I already created the add rows but my problem is, the value of the id that I created doesn't increment. I just stick to 1 result.

I also want to include remove rows so whenever I click the button "remove" the row with specific id will remove.

[Here's my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z51z3jj1/)

```
<script>
var rowID;
function myFunction() {
    rowID++;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    rowID=1;
    cell1.innerHTML = "###";
    cell2.innerHTML = "###";
    cell3.innerHTML = rowID;
    cell4.innerHTML = "<button id=''>Remove</button>";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the debugger, inspect the value of `rowID`. It will be `NaN`.

Comment: you set `rowID=1;` halfway down - set that when you initialise the variable (outside your function)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set it back here

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
rowID=1; //<-- NOT NEED
cell1.innerHTML = "###";
```

remove this row.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z51z3jj1/1/). And init it with `var rowID = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your variable to 0 when defining it in order to add 1 to it with the ++ operator. Also remove the rowID = 1 (it resets it to 1) in your code as following:

```
<script>
var rowID = 0;
function myFunction() {
    rowID++;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "###";
    cell2.innerHTML = "###";
    cell3.innerHTML = rowID;
    cell4.innerHTML = "<button id=''>Remove</button>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a couple of typos, see in the comments:

```
//rowId must be initialized to a number or you'll get Nan with rowId++
var rowID = 0;

function myFunction() {

  rowID++;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

  //this is the reason of your bug
  //rowID=1;

  cell1.innerHTML = "###";
  cell2.innerHTML = "###";
  cell3.innerHTML = rowID;
  cell4.innerHTML = "<button id=''>Remove</button>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `rowID=1` so every time it will have value `1`. Also you need to set `rowID=0` if you want to increment it otherwise if you don'y initialize it it will result in `NaN`

```
<script>
var rowID;
function myFunction() {
    rowID++;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    rowID=1;
    cell1.innerHTML = "###";
    cell2.innerHTML = "###";
    cell3.innerHTML = rowID;
    cell4.innerHTML = "<button id="+rowID+" onclick='Remove(this)'>Remove</button>";
}

function Remove(btn){
btn.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z51z3jj1/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowID = 0;
function myFunction() {
    rowID++;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    //rowID=1;
    cell1.innerHTML = "###";
    cell2.innerHTML = "###";
    cell3.innerHTML = rowID;
    cell4.innerHTML = "<button id=''>Remove</button>";
}
```

1. Initialize the var rowID to 0 during declaration (considered good practice)
2. You made a silly mistake of assigning the rowid in the function itself.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z51z3jj1/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove elements, this is an option

```
row.setAttribute("onclick","remove(this)");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z51z3jj1/4/